# How to hide actionbar in Activity, but show in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, hide, show

i have a fragment from  an activity, i hide the actionbar in my activity like so `supportActionBar?.hide()` in the `onCreate` function of the activity when the app first starts. When the fragment is created, i have the following code in the  `onCreate` to show the actionbar in the fragment:

```
activity?.supportActionBar?.show()
activity?.supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.host)
```

The problem is, that when i go back to the main Activity, the actionbar is now there. Is there a way to permanently keep the actionbar disabled for the main Activity, but have it showing for the fragments?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the activity life cycle call. When you went from MainActivity to other fragment/activity the MainActivity goes in onPause() state which is called after onCreate() for the first time. You can do either of the two things: 1. again hide the action bar in OnResume() method or use the variable or shared preferences to toggle

Comment: @IshtdeepHora hiding it again works, but it kinda feels like a hackish way. Can you explain what the second option with the "variable or shared preferences" is?

Comment: I was saying put the constant value after class declaration and check whether the constant value is restored in OnCreate() and onResume() but again you have to check the condition and implement the hiding method. Have you tried this way in your manifest file

<activity
   // ...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
   // ...
   </activity>

Answer (score 0):

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```